# how to check for multiple files existence in a makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

How can I check for a multiple files existence in a makefile? Is this condition correct?

```
if [ -a fileName1 && -a fileName2]
 then
     rm fileName1
 fi
```

Comment: No. RT*M: [`man [`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: That's not actually a make question as written/asked. That's a shell question. And you are missing a space before the final `]` (spacing matters). But also as Biffen indicates your internal test syntax is wrong as well.